# Obter hora minutos e segundos em javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de sabe como faço em Javascript para obter a hora? Um número que representa a data e hora e segundos atual. Sei que conseguimos o objeto para data e hora e segundos através de:

```
const data = new Date();
```

**Não** entendi muito bem isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em JavaScript podes guardar uma data num objeto (instância) `Date`. Essa instância tem métodos a partir dos quais podes extrair os seus componentes como data, ano, horas, etc...

Podes [ler mais sobre isso aqui na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), mas para dar um exemplo com horas podes extrair e criar uma array que depois convertes em string com os dois pontos a separar os valores:

```js
const data = new Date(); // momento atual 
const horas = data.getHours();
const minutos = data.getMinutes();
const segundos = data.getSeconds();

const hhmmmss = [horas, minutos, segundos].join(':');
console.log(hhmmmss);
```

Porém, para esse tipo de representação podes também usar o [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) que te dá exatamente isso formatado para o *locale* que quiseres:

```js
const data = new Date(); // momento atual 
console.log(data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR'));
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado